# Hadoop : Phoenix Table Change Listeners in Java

Tags: apache, hadoop, apache-phoenix

I have a business need to listen on the table events on the operations performed in HBase Tables. We are accessing them DDL/DML via Apache Phoenix.

Just like ojdbc connections and listeners(mentioned below), do we have any frameworks which would assist me achieving the same to listen on Phoenix Tables.

[jdbc: oracle database change notification & duplicate events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697500/jdbc-oracle-database-change-notification-duplicate-events)